# Pandas.pivot replace some existing values with NaN

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have to read some table from a SQL Server and merge their values in a single data structure for a machine learning project. I'm using Pandas and in particular `pd.read_sql_query` for read the values and `pd.merge` to fuse them.
One table has at least 80 milion rows and if I try to read it entirely it occupies all my memory storage (it's not so much, only 20gb but I've got a small ssd), so I decided to divide it in chunk of 100000 rows:

```
df_bilanci = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT [IdBilancioRiclassificato], [IdBilancio], [Importo] FROM dbo.Bilanci', conn, chunksize=100000)
```

One single chunk will be like this:

|  | IdBilancioRiclassificato | IdBilancio | Importo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10.0 | 7001.0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 11.0 | 7001.0 | 502643.0 |
| 2 | 12.0 | 7001.0 | -4550.0 |
| 3 | 10.0 | 7002.0 | 654654.0 |
| 4 | 11.0 | 7002.0 | 0.0 |
| 5 | 12.0 | 7002.0 | 0.0 |

I'm interested to have the values of IdBilancioRiclassificato as columns (there are a total of 97 unique values for this column, so they have to be 97 columns), so I used `pd.pivot` on every chunk and then `pd.concat` plus merge to put together all the data:

```
for chunk in df_bilanci:

    chunk.reset_index()
    chunk_pivoted = pd.pivot(data=chunk, 
                            index='IdBilancio', 
                            columns='IdBilancioRiclassificato',  
                            values='Importo'
                            )    

    df_aziende_bil = pd.concat([df_aziende_bil, pd.merge(left=df_aziende_anagrafe, right=chunk_pivoted, left_on='ID', right_index=True)])
```

At this point however, the `chunk_pivoted` dataframe has some values replaced with NaN values but if I look in the table the values exist.

The result expected is a table like this one:

| IdBilancio | 10.0 | 11.0 | 12.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7001.0 | 0.0 | 502643.0 | -4550.0 |
| 7002.0 | 654654.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |

but i've got something like this:

| IdBilancio | 10.0 | 11.0 | 12.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7001.0 | 0.0 | NaN | -4550.0 |
| 7002.0 | 654654.0 | NaN | NaN |

Comment: i doubt that the result actuyll looks like that all position where you wrote 0.0 have , so i am guessing not that value

Comment: Will you share examples of ```df_aziende_anagrafe``` and ```df_aziende_bil```? You pivot part returns exactly your claimed expected outcome.